# NFS traffic going to interface with different IP address but same subnet

Tags: nfs

My NFS server has 3 interfaces: **0**: 1Gb, **1**: 10Gb, **2**: 10Gb.

Iface 0 is just used for admin purposes and 1/2 are for two different mounts.

All of the interfaces are on the same subnet (/24).

| server | ----> iface 0/1/2 ----> |private switch| ----> |all clients|

My clients are configured to connect to nfs via interfaces **1** and **2**.

```
$ mount
...
iface1:/home on /home type nfs4 (rw,relatime,vers=4.0,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,port=0,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=172.1.1.3,local_lock=none,addr=172.1.1.1)
iface2:/scratch on /scratchlair type nfs4 (rw,relatime,vers=4.0,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,port=0,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=172.1.1.3,local_lock=none,addr=172.1.1.2)
...
```

Where iface **1** and **2** are 172.1.1.{1,2}, respectively.
Iface 0 is 172.1.1.5.

My problem is that on the server, I'm seeing all the traffic going to iface **0**, via nload.
Ifaces **1** and **2** show no traffic.

This goes the same for all  10 clients connected to the nfs server.

What is causing traffic to go to iface **0**, and how can I force the nfs client's traffic across the configured interface?

Comment: what's you're default route set to? How does changing the route affect the NFS path?

Comment: You may have to put your interfaces in different subnets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make this work you have to configure separate routing tables and rules for all three inet interfaces and enable `arp_filter`.
You also might first want to test this in a VM environment as you can easily interrupt any connection during the next steps and there will be definitely some hickups.

---

First enable `arp_filter`.

```
sysctl net.ipv4.conf.default.arp_filter=1
```

To make it permanent add this to your `/etc/sysctl.conf`. Depending on your distribution you can also place it into a file beneath `/etc/sysctl.d/`.

```
echo net.ipv4.conf.default.arp_filter = 1 >> /etc/sysctl.conf
```

---

Now let's add the routing tables.

```
cat << TABLES >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables 
101 rt1
102 rt2
103 rt3
TABLES
```

Assuming you have a `/24` netmask and your default gateway is `172.1.1.254`. Further, interface 0, 1 and 2 are `eth0`, `eth1` and `eth2` in the following example which might no match your setup, so you would have to adopt it.

```
ip route add 172.1.1.0/24 dev eth0 src 172.1.1.5 table rt1
ip route add table rt1 default via 172.1.1.254 dev eth0
ip rule add table rt1 from 172.1.1.5

ip route add 172.1.1.0/24 dev eth1 src 172.1.1.1 table rt2
ip route add table rt2 default via 172.1.1.254 dev eth1 
ip rule add table rt2 from 172.1.1.1    

ip route add 172.1.1.0/24 dev eth2 src 172.1.1.2 table rt3
ip route add table rt3 default via 172.1.1.254 dev eth2
ip rule add table rt2 from 172.1.1.2
```

To make these routing tables and rules permanent you have to add the above steps to your NIC configuration. On a RHEL based system, that would be as follows.

Routes and rules for `eth0`.

```
cat << ROUTE > /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth0
172.1.1.0/24 dev eth0 src 172.1.1.5 table rt1
table rt1 default via 172.1.1.254 dev eth0
ROUTE

cat << RULE > /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/rule-eth0
table rt1 from 172.1.1.5
RULE
```

Routes and rules for `eth1`.

```
cat << ROUTE > /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth1
172.1.1.0/24 dev eth1 src 172.1.1.1 table rt2
table rt2 default via 172.1.1.254 dev eth1
ROUTE

cat << RULE > /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/rule-eth1
table rt2 from 172.1.1.1   
RULE
```

Routes and rules for `eth2`.

```
cat << ROUTE > /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth2
172.1.1.0/24 dev eth2 src 172.1.1.2 table rt3
table rt3 default via 172.1.1.254 dev eth2
ROUTE

cat << RULE > /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/rule-eth2
table rt3 from 172.1.1.2   
RULE
```

---

It might be easier as outlined in the comments already to just use different subnets for the interfaces and assign IP aliases on the clients for the different subnets.

I have tested this in a VM environment with a CentOS7 NFS server.

Comment: Worked like a charm, however I believe you meant `ip rule add table rt3`, instead of `rt2` for the third interface.

Comment: Good to hear and yes you are right, it must be `rt3`. Thanks for double checking, updated answer.